# Jasmine test a function was called with a "similar" object?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Suppose I have a function that does this:

```
var createDeferredAction = function (args) {
    var deferral = $q.defer();

    var action = {
       args: args
       deferral: deferral;
    };

    $scope.$emit('load-module', action);

    return deferral.promise;
}
```

Then in my test, I want to so something like:

```
myService.createDeferredAction({foo: 'bar'});

var expected = {
    args: {foo: 'bar'},
    deferral: jasmine.anySimilar($q.defer())
}

expect($scopeSpy.$emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('load-module', expected);
```

That is, when jasmine inspects that `expected` object, I don't want it to try and look for the exact instance of the deferral, I just want it to check that an object matching the signature was passed in. E.g. *any* instance of a deferral.

I know that I can mock `$q.defer()` and return a known value I can use in my expectation, but I'd rather not have to mock `$q.defer()`.

Is such a thing possible with Jasmine?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it but i think you can achieve this by getting the arguments from the method call and then check just the type of the properties you're interested in. So with Jasmine 2 something like:

```
expect($scopeSpy.$emit.calls.argsFor(1).deferral).toEqual(jasmine.any(Deferred));
```

or with Jasmine 1.3

```
expect($scopeSpy.$emit.calls[0].args[1].deferral).toEqual(jasmine.any(Deferred));
```